# CKKS Encoding scheme explanation

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation

I have been going over the [CKKS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf) Homomorphic Encryption scheme but I can't seem to understand how the mapping takes place while encoding. I don't get what the line below is trying to convey. I saw this line in a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/cokdkx/explanation_of_the_ckks_scheme/) on Reddit. It would be super great if someone could illustrate this scheme with an example. Thank you!

> The floating point arithmetic operated during the encoding, which maps a N/2 complex array to a N real array, and then rounds to the nearest integer after the scaling of the float numbers resulting from the complex embedding map.

Comment: I think that it would be helpful if you linked the paper and specified from which part of it you took this sentence, so that people reading your question can understand the context...

Comment: Ok @HilderVitorLimaPereira

Comment: One concrete way to understand the how the scheme looks is to look at implementations of it. I believe CKKS (also known as HEAAN) is implemented in most major FHE libraries. It looks like Palisade implements CKKS encoding in C++ [here](https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-release/-/blob/master/src/core/lib/encoding/ckkspackedencoding.cpp), for example. Of course a conceptual answer would still be useful, but if someone doesn't give one this is an option.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the link @Mark! I'll go through them!

Comment: Are you not used with the concepts of abstract algebra used in the paper? Are you at least used to the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira yes, I'm quite a beginner in this field so the algebra looks very daunting to me :( I have read about the CRT earlier, but I'm not sure how this is effective here